# Need some information about using cocos2d in iPad

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, ipad

I  need some information about using cocos2d in iPad.

Can we use 2048x2048 sprite sheets ? I read in this form that we can use but with limitation not more than 3 or 4 sprite sheets.
But, I have 10 animations in my game.  maximum of 4 animations run at a time.

Can we use the CCDirectors  in AppDelegate in the same way as we use in iPhone ?

```
if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:CCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
    [CCDirector setDirectorType:CCDirectorTypeDefault];

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setPixelFormat:kPixelFormatRGBA8888];
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
```

What can be the maximum size of the image that we can use?

Any  limitations regarding the cocos2d and iPad please post them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPad resolution is 1024x768. It doesn't make sense to use higher resolution images in your game unless you intend to zoom in to see a LOT more detail. Even so you need to evaluate if you really want to do this. If you do, be sure to turn on mipmapping for your textures in Cocos2D.

If you use higher resolution images, the iOS device's PowerVR chip (video processor) is going to pay and your game will perform much slower. If you can help it I would either tile much lower pixel sized images (say 256x256 or lower). In the end it depends on how fast your game runs on your target device.

Comment: Thank You.
I have images of size less than 256x256. I am using CCSpriteSheet and I used Zwoptex to make a spriteSheet of images. The sprite sheet is 2048x2048 pixel size.  Should I avoid of using the sprite sheet of that big size ?
Thank You.

Comment: @srikanth: It needs to be MUCH smaller. Unless there is a good reason for it to be bigger than 1024x768, scale your texture down to 1024x768 (maximum).

Comment: I iPhone should I make the texture not more than 480x320.
Thank You.